# Layer on click event not firing in Firefox but working fine in Chrome,Edge

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, browser

I am using ESRI JS API 3.24 in my application.

I am using following code to open specific URL within the application when click on the layer.

```
var lyrUrl = "Path_To_Layer";
var myLyr = new FeatureLayer(lyrUrl, {
 id: "some_id",
 mode: 1,
 outFields: ['ID', 'Name_English']
});

//Code for the specific URL to open in a new window
myLyr.on("click", function(evt) {
 var enName = myLyr._downGr.attributes.Name_English;
 window.open('main/' + enName + '/index.html');
});
```

> The issue is that the click event is working fine in chrome, Edge but
>   not in Firefox.

I mean not working is that when click on the layer, the link open in new page/tab but in Firefox, nothing happen at all.

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler works fine for me in Firefox - [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/pgbwyq6o/) - if you click on one of the red points in Firefox the alert shows for me.

Comment: Hey @GavinR, its very strange behavior of FF. It seems that now its working fine. Thanks for the answer.